# python opencv. I want to get the pixel values where r=b=g

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
img = cv2.imread('/home/Desktop/image/findgray1.jpg')
b = 0
g = 0
r = 0
count = 0
for i in range (img.shape[0]): 
    for j in range (img.shape[1]):
        for c in range(img.shape[2]):
            if img[i][j]==[[b],[g],[r]]:
                count+=1
                b+=1
                g+=1
                r+=1
print(count)
```

This is my code. I want to get pixel values where `r=g=b`, eg:`(0,0,0)`,`(1,1,1)`.....`(255,255,255)` values.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code runs without error and counts the gray pixels:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
count = 0
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img.shape[1]):
        if img[i][j][0] == img[i][j][1] == img[i][j][2]:
            count+=1

print count
```

Comment: and if you want to count only a specific gray value `(g,g,g)`, replace the `if` line with `if (img[i][j] == g).all():`